# 19.10 stuck on boot screen

Tags: 19.10, xps

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10 on XPS 15 7590 and after doing `sudo nvidia-xconfig`, I rebooted the computer and I've been stuck on the purple Boot screen for 20 minutes now.  The only solution I found online was adding `nomodeset` in the grub file to disable Nvidia but I don't want to do that as I need my Nvidia graphics card running.

Comment: are you able to log in using the terminal option: Ctrl+Alt+F1?

Comment: nomodeset does *not* disable your Nvidia, except during boot, so it is worth trying that.